# How to avoid dispose of context in async call in .NET core

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, backgroundworker

I'm having some slow calls in my api so in order not to block my UI, I implemented a background worker service following this [tutorial](https://blog.elmah.io/async-processing-of-long-running-tasks-in-asp-net-core/). Inside my `_backgroundWorkerQueue` I have

```
_backgroundWorkerQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async token =>
{
    await client.ExecuteAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);
    await _projectRepository.Update(id, "Update", "unlock");
});
```

The second line, `await _projectRepository.Update`, throws me an error that the context has been disposed and the update fails. I set my service to transient and my context as transient in order to test it out this way but I still got the same error. Any thoughts and ideas of how can I avoid and fix this, if possible, without usage of other libraries as Hangfire etc.

Comment: You don't need that `BackgroundWorkerQueue`, it does what a `Channel<T>` does already.

Comment: The doc already explains how to use a DbContext in the [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) section of the [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) tutorial: Inject `IServiceProvider` and use it to get a scope and a DbContext from it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you don't need to create a new class for this. The [Channel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) class already does far more than this `BackgroundWorkerQueue`.

As for the specific problem, it's described in the BackgroundService docs  [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) in the section [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task). The problem is that a hosted service is essentially a singleton, not transient. It's created when the application starts and disposed when it stops. The service itself is registered as a transient, but since its owner is the application host itself, it acts as a singleton.

The solution shown in the docs is to inject `IServiceProvider` into your service and use it to construct a new scope and new services from it as needed

> To use scoped services within a BackgroundService, create a scope. No scope is created for a hosted service by default.

```
public class ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService> _logger;

    public ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService(IServiceProvider services, 
        ILogger<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService> logger)
    {
        Services = services;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IServiceProvider Services { get; }
    ...

    private async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service is working.");

        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var scopedProcessingService = 
                scope.ServiceProvider
                    .GetRequiredService<IScopedProcessingService>();

            await scopedProcessingService.DoWork(stoppingToken);
        }
    }
```

The very next section [Queued Background Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks) addresses exactly the scenario you described, with a Channel-based `Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>` queue

History note: the docs uses QueueBackgroundWorkItem in the past. When the sample code changed, some of the docs remained the same. The `QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync` method should probably be named just `EnqueueAsync`. The sample does abstract the underlying queue implementation though

```
public interface IBackgroundTaskQueue
{
    ValueTask QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask> workItem);

    ValueTask<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> DequeueAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class BackgroundTaskQueue : IBackgroundTaskQueue
{
    private readonly Channel<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> _queue;

    public BackgroundTaskQueue(int capacity)
    {
        // Capacity should be set based on the expected application load and
        // number of concurrent threads accessing the queue.            
        // BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait will cause calls to WriteAsync() to return a task,
        // which completes only when space became available. This leads to backpressure,
        // in case too many publishers/calls start accumulating.
        var options = new BoundedChannelOptions(capacity)
        {
            FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait
        };
        _queue = Channel.CreateBounded<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>>(options);
    }

    public async ValueTask QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(
        Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask> workItem)
    {
        if (workItem == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
        }

        await _queue.Writer.WriteAsync(workItem);
    }

    public async ValueTask<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> DequeueAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var workItem = await _queue.Reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);

        return workItem;
    }
}
```

The `IBackgroundTaskQueue` service should be injected into producers and the BackgroundService class. Producers will use `QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync` to post work and the service will use `DequeueAsync` to receive tasks:

```
public class QueuedHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<QueuedHostedService> _logger;

    public QueuedHostedService(IBackgroundTaskQueue taskQueue, 
        ILogger<QueuedHostedService> logger)
    {
        TaskQueue = taskQueue;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IBackgroundTaskQueue TaskQueue { get; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            $"Queued Hosted Service is running.{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"{Environment.NewLine}Tap W to add a work item to the " +
            $"background queue.{Environment.NewLine}");

        await BackgroundProcessing(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task BackgroundProcessing(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var workItem = 
                await TaskQueue.DequeueAsync(stoppingToken);

            try
            {
                await workItem(stoppingToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, 
                    "Error occurred executing {WorkItem}.", nameof(workItem));
            }
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Queued Hosted Service is stopping.");

        await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

The sample code *can* be simplified by returning a `ChannelReader<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>>` or an `IAsyncEnumerable<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>>. Using` IAsyncEnumerable<>` hides the internal implementation just like the original example did:

```
public interface IBackgroundTaskQueue
{
    ValueTask QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask> workItem);

    ValueTask<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> DequeueAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    IAsyncEnumerable<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> ReadAllAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class BackgroundTaskQueue : IBackgroundTaskQueue
{

...
    public IAsyncEnumerable<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> ReadAllAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _queue.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

This allows using `await foreach` in the `BackgroundProcessing` method:

```
private async Task BackgroundProcessing(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    await foreach(var workItem in TaskQueue.ReadAllAsync(stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            await workItem(stoppingToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, 
                "Error occurred executing {WorkItem}.", nameof(workItem));
        }
    }
}
```

Combined with our scoped service, and assuming the queue accepts `Func<IProductRepository,CancellationToken, ValueTask>` :

```
private async Task BackgroundProcessing(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    await foreach(var workItem in TaskQueue.ReadAllAsync(stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var repo = scope.ServiceProvider
                                .GetRequiredService<IProjectRepository>();
                await workItem(repo,stoppingToken);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, 
                "Error occurred executing {WorkItem}.", nameof(workItem));
        }        
    }
}
```